# Как добавить docker-volume к docker-compose в проекте?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, rust, actix-web

У меня есть API написанная на Rust с базой данных PostgreSQL. Данные проекта я храню в контейнерах докер , используя docker-compose я запускаю его. Появилась необходимость использовать docker-volume  но я не совсем понимаю как объединить две технологии докера.

Все мое понимание останавливается на создании некоторой сущности через "docker volume create". Как связать проект с этой сущностью непонятно.Как я понял, нужно прописать volume в .env файл но после попытки , проект перестал запускаться и пришлось откатывать версию. В docker compose прописал volume;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Dm9.png)
Но после очередного запуска программа выдает мне ошибку: service "postgres" refers to undefined volume pg_database: invalid compose project.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146557/discussion-on-question-by-afins---docker-volume--docker-compose--); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.